# Using Flash Builder to connect to a VPN on Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash-builder, vpn

I have written a program that links to a site I have written but for it to work I have to connect to a VPN. I was wondering if there was a way of creating another button to connect directly to my chosen VPN connection.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Access to Android's VPN Service isn't available from Flash Builder / Action Script.

Comment: Is there a way of getting the menu open though? I.E - a button would open: Menu / Settings / VPN ??